# How do I import NLTK to Python 3.7 on a Mac?

Tags: python, macos

I have been trying to import the Natural Language Toolkit (NLTK) as per the code provided on https://www.nltk.org/install.html.

This code works on the terminal window on my mac (10.14), but refuses to import NLTK onto the interpreter provided with Python (IDLE).

I have already tried changing the directory by importing os module. (Changed the directory to the default Python library on macOS). This in turn yields errors from the NLTK scripts itself.

This is the code I ran

```
>>> import os

>>> os.getcwd()

>>> os.chdir('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages')

>>> import nltk
```

I expected the nltk to successfully import after changing the directory.

However, it shows errors in the NLTK scripts itself (I'm assuming) which are as follows:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       import nltk
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/**init**.py", line 99,
>   in
>
> ```
> from nltk.internals import config_java
> ```
>
> File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/nltk/internals.py", line 28,
>   in
>
> ```
> from six import string_types
> ```
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'"

Comment: Can you import it without changing directory? If not, you are missing the `six` package.

Comment: I have Python 3.7, which apparently is supposed to have pip, but when I ask for the six package, it shows "invalid syntax" error, highlighting "install".

Is there another way to install the six package?

Comment: It has been asked for multiple times. It's a duplicate, please google the question.

Comment: True, thanks. Although I had to perform trial-and-error till I figured it was the version of Python that was creating a problem for me. The problem is solved and I am now using v. 2.7.16. (couldn't find this on google, but I suspect it is the same for many other mac users)